# How would I work out the area of a shape that isn't a circle but has no ovals

Tags: area

Say for example I have a shape that is an oval which ddoesn't have straight lines(the wobble) how would I work out the area? What shape would it even be?

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: How you would find the area depends completely on how the shape in question is given to you.

Comment: I added an image of the shape

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is an image, then the best you can do is probably to color it in in your favorite image editor, and ask the editor to count how many black pixels the image contains. (In Gimp, for example, use the Color Select tool to select the shape and its interior; then Colors > Info > Histogram will tell you how many pixels are selected). That may well give sufficient precision for whatever your purpose in finding the area is.

Otherwise you do need some kind of equations of functions that define the shape exactly.

Comment: I'm not an artist or anything, i'm just curious as at school we get taught formulas for hemispheres, etcetera. But what if the shape can't be defined like the above - what shape even is that - so is there anyway to work it out?

Comment: The shape is a basic version of a pond my uncle is digging and I was just curious as to how you work out the area, volume and perimeter

Comment: @Harry: Unless you have a mathematical description of the shape, you don't _calculate_ its area. Just _measure_ it instead, which is what I'm describing a method for.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was confused about.